# How to add total of multiple repeats in C?

Tags: c

I am writing a simple C program which takes data from user and does some maths. Here is my code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main(void) {

        int semester_1,grade_1,grade_2,grade_3,subtotal,total_marks,average;
        printf("Enter number of semester you to check");
        scanf("%d", &semester_1);

        while (semester_1 > 0) {
            printf("Enter marks for first subject");
            scanf("%d", &grade_1);

            printf("Enter marks for second subject");
            scanf("%d", &grade_2);

            printf("Enter marks for third subject");
            scanf("%d", &grade_3);

            subtotal = grade_1 + grade_2 + grade_3;
            total_marks = subtotal / 300 * 100;
            printf("Your average this semester is %d", total_marks);

            semester_1--;
        }
        average = semester_1 / 100 * total_marks;
        printf("Your final average for all semesters is %d", average);
    }
```

The problem with this code is that when I run the program returns 0 for final average for all semesters.
I wanted to get the final average for all semesters. Lets say if user enters 3 for numbers of semester they want to check and then they will be enter marks 3 times and then final average will be displayed, but it only gives 0.

Comment: Your code has an important bug at this line `scanf("%d", &semester_1);`, try typing `asdad`, what happens?

Comment: Use floting point arithmetics. Unless you have >=100 semester_1, it will be always 0. Worse: which value has `semester_1` after the loop?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because here:

```
total_marks = subtotal / 300 * 100;
```

`subtotal` is less than `300 * 100`. And since both the operands of `/` are of type `int`, integer division is performed resulting in `total_marks` becoming 0.

Fix it by changing the type of `total_marks` to `float`, or more preferably, `double`. Then, cast one of the operands of `/` to `float` if you changed `total_marks`'s type to `float` or `double` if you changed `total_marks`'s type to `double`. The cast makes sure that integer division is not performed and floating-point division is performed.

You might need to do the same with `average`.

---

**Fixed Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

  int semester_1, grade_1, grade_2, grade_3, subtotal; /* Better to use an array */
  double total_marks, average;

  printf("Enter number of semester you to check");
  scanf("%d", &semester_1);

  while (semester_1 > 0) {
    printf("Enter marks for first subject");
    scanf("%d", &grade_1);

    printf("Enter marks for second subject");
    scanf("%d", &grade_2);

    printf("Enter marks for third subject");
    scanf("%d", &grade_3);

    subtotal = grade_1 + grade_2 + grade_3;
    total_marks = (double)subtotal / 300 * 100; /* Note the cast */
    printf("Your average this semester is %f", total_marks); /* Note the change in the format specifier */

    semester_1--;
  }
  average = (double)semester_1 / 100 * total_marks; /* Note the cast */
  printf("Your final average for all semesters is %f", average); /* Note the change in the format specifier */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main(void) {

        int semester_1,grade_1,grade_2,grade_3,subtotal,total_marks,average;
        printf("Enter number of semester you to check");
        scanf("%d", &semester_1);

        while (semester_1 > 0) {
            printf("Enter marks for first subject");
            scanf("%d", &grade_1);

            printf("Enter marks for second subject");
            scanf("%d", &grade_2);

            printf("Enter marks for third subject");
            scanf("%d", &grade_3);

            subtotal = grade_1 + grade_2 + grade_3;
            total_marks = subtotal / 300.0 * 100.0;
            printf("Your average this semester is %d", total_marks);

            semester_1--;
        }
        average = semester_1 / 100.0 * total_marks;
        printf("Your final average for all semesters is %d", average);
    }
```

Rounding errors

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several issues.  The first is the one pointed out by Cool Guy: dividing small integer by bigger integer will lead to the result being zero due to integer truncation.

The second is that you aren't keeping a running total, and you're decrementing the number of semesters for your loop counter.
You should add a new variable that stores the cumulative sum of each semester, and you should save the initial value of semester_1

(Also, style-wise,

`for (int i = 0; i < num_semesters; i++)`

is much more readable than (and preserves the value of num_semesters)

`while(semester_1 > 0)`
)